# What happens to apps with license verification once they’re removed from the Play Store?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I use an app that’s tied to my account, when I open it, it refuses to proceed unless I own it on the google play account I’m logged in currently. Once I’m logged in the correct account though, it doesn’t do those checks repeatedly, I assume it already knows I have a license.

What will happen if the app ever gets removed from the play store though? Will I still be able to access it with my current account?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you can access it**

- From Google play help [App removed from Google Play Store](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/12246761?hl=en)

> *What happens if an app is removed from Google Play?*
>
> > The app will no longer be available to download on Google Play. If you have the app installed on your device, you can continue to use the app, however you will not be able to update your app...

> *If an app is removed from Google Play, will the app be removed from my device?*
>
> > No, the app will not be removed from your device. You can continue to use the app...

I assume second clarification refers to [Play protect removing/deactivating harmful apps](https://support.google.com/android/answer/2812853?hl=en)

- From personal experience - I had purchased a scanning app (CamScanner)
  that is currently banned in my country (India). I use it without any problems (irrespective of Google Play Protect being enabled or disabled). Of course, I can't update the app from Play store.